# org-mode , export , how to 'force' newline on lines between paragraphs?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, newlines

I have an org-mode file, some sub-sections have some big paragraphs.
When I export as html the whole paragraphs are displayed as single lines.

I understand that I have to put a '\\' on every line, a bit PITA, its around 4000 lines there. Is there any way, a parameter perhaps, that forces new line to each line that sits between paragraphs?

thx

Answer (score 37):

is `#+OPTIONS: \n:t` what you want (see `org-export-preserve-breaks`)?

place this line anywhere in your org-file to preserve line breaks.

ref: *The Org Manual/Exporting/Export settings*

Comment: what if I only want this option for a specific section?

Comment: @xeruf I don't mean to be rude. But couldn't you just correct those sections in the org doc itself.

Comment: @Dhawan I think it's a fair demand, say, a dedicated section for poem? some people like their text being compact visually.  @xeruf usually for each file-scope `#+keyword`, there is a corresponding subtree property `EXPORT_keyword`, but unfortunately, AFAIK, not for this `#+OPTIONS` one.

Comment: @nichijou Aah! I see, now. Thank you. So the ask is to override the global variable org-export-preserve-breaks from nil to t. If this is the ask, then it might be possible to set override the https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html the argument at sub section if we set the property `org-export-preserve-breaks` to t inside the sub-section using the command `org-set-property` where the property name is `ORG-EXPORT-PERSERVE-BREAKS` and the value being `t`.

Answer (score 9):

To separate paragraphs by a single line all you need is to add an empty line between each paragraph in your org-file like following:

```
First paragraph

Second paragraph
```

`\\` is only required to add additional empty lines.

Comment: thank you, as I understand now, each paragraph is limited to a single line? or not..

Comment: Each paragraph can be as long as you want. To create a new paragraph, you need to press enter twice in your org-file(== one empty line in-between). If you just press enter once, you'll only see a whitespace between those lines in your exported html file (since according to org-mode, you didn't create a new paragraph).

Answer (score 3):

Any number of `\\`, `@@latex:\\@@` or `OPTIONS: \n:t` did not work for me. I think this is because of the way LaTeX handles paragraphs (can't have many linebreaks between two paragraphs).

I solved it by using `\bigskip` (there's also smallskip and medskip, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11338/why-does-my-linebreak-not-work), no need to use `@@latex: @@` here)