# new lines in org mode export to LaTeX

Tags: org-export, latex

This is similar to ([this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21556/org-mode-export-how-to-force-newline-on-lines-between-paragraphs)).

I would like to export the following `org-mode` document to LaTeX:

```
* Test
  text 1
  text 2
  text 3

  - list 1
  - list 2
  - list 3

  #+BEGIN_definition
  environment 1
  environment 2
  #+END_definition
```

I want to preserve the line breaks to achieve a tex document looking like:

```
\section{Test}
text 1\\
text 2\\
text 3

\begin{itemize}
\item list 1
\item list 2
\item list 3
\end{itemize}

\begin{definition}
environment 1\\
environment 2
\end{definition}
```

i.e. I would like to append `\\` after each line preceding regular text (for example, it should not be appended before a blank line, `\item`, or `\end{...}`).

I can almost achieve this using `#+OPTIONS: \n:t` but this appends `\\` to each line, not just lines preceding regular text. Are there simple ways to achieve this? What configuration settings should I try to play with?